# Why is my other checkbox panel going missing in this weird custom checkbox issue?

Tags: html, css

The fiddle is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/hbruvex7/).

Should be like this, in essence.

[image]

But in my custom checkbox, as you'll see in fiddle, it shows like this.

[image]

**Note there are two inputs in checkgroup before a label**

**HTML**

```
<div class=" text-left"><span class="font-weight-bold">Include</span> <span class="font-weight-bold">Exclude</span>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div class="checkGroup"><input type="checkbox" class="include" value="Chicken"> <input type="checkbox" class="exclude"> <label>
                Chicken
                </label></div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="checkGroup"><input type="checkbox" class="include" value="Turkey"> <input type="checkbox" class="exclude"> <label>
                Turkey
                </label></div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="checkGroup"><input type="checkbox" class="include" value="Beef"> <input type="checkbox" class="exclude"> <label>
                Beef
                </label></div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="checkGroup"><input type="checkbox" class="include" value="Pork"> <input type="checkbox" class="exclude"> <label>
                Pork
                </label></div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="checkGroup"><input type="checkbox" class="include" value="Fish"> <input type="checkbox" class="exclude"> <label>
                Fish
                </label></div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="checkGroup"><input type="checkbox" class="include" value="No Meat - Vegetarian Only"> <input type="checkbox" class="exclude"> <label>
                No Meat - Vegetarian Only
                </label></div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="checkGroup"><input type="checkbox" class="include" value="No Meat - Vegan Only"> <input type="checkbox" class="exclude"> <label>
                No Meat - Vegan Only
                </label></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.checkGroup {
  display: inline;
  .exclude {
    margin-left: 2em;
  }
  .include {
    margin-left: 2em;
  }
  label {
    margin-left: 2em;
  }
  /* Base for label styling */
  [type="checkbox"]:not(:checked),
  [type="checkbox"]:checked {
    position: absolute;
    left: -9999px;
  }
  [type="checkbox"]:not(:checked)+label,
  [type="checkbox"]:checked+label {
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 1.95em;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  /* checkbox aspect */
  [type="checkbox"]:not(:checked)+label:before,
  [type="checkbox"]:checked+label:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 1.25em;
    height: 1.25em;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  }
  /* checked mark aspect */
  [type="checkbox"]:not(:checked)+label:after,
  [type="checkbox"]:checked+label:after {
    content: '✔';
    position: absolute;
    top: .2em;
    left: .275em;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    line-height: 0.8;
    color: #09ad7e;
    transition: all .2s;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  }
  /* checked mark aspect changes */
  [type="checkbox"]:not(:checked)+label:after {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  [type="checkbox"]:checked+label:after {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  /* disabled checkbox */
  [type="checkbox"]:disabled:not(:checked)+label:before,
  [type="checkbox"]:disabled:checked+label:before {
    box-shadow: none;
    border-color: #bbb;
    background-color: #ddd;
  }
  [type="checkbox"]:disabled:checked+label:after {
    color: #999;
  }
  [type="checkbox"]:disabled+label {
    color: #aaa;
  }
}
```

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: The downvote wasn't me, but you only have one `<label>` for two `<input>` elements. It's the label's `:before` that makes up the checkbox, so you'll need two of them per row if you want two checkboxes.

Comment: Ref: *Why the downvote*. Any of these: [toomuchcode](http://idownvotedbecau.se/toomuchcode/), [noresearch](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/) and [nodebugging](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/).

Comment: @Obsidian Age I tried that on my actual code but the checkboxes don't click at all. Switching to native checkboxes makes them work fine however.

Comment: How many states are there? What should happen when one clicks the label? It should switch from include to exclude or pass through `neither` state, too?

Comment: Checked or unchecked are the only two states. If you remove the CSS code in my fiddle, it clicks, but when the CSS code is applied  (after applying extra blank label), as in the fiddle, no checkbox changes state .

Comment: So there are 4 possible states: `00`, `10`, `01` & `11`. Correct? My question stands: what should happen when you click on `<label>`?

Comment: Actually 2 states, ignore the disabled states for now. When I click on a label, in this buggy code, nothing happens either. Of course when CSS code is removed, and native takes place, it all works as expected. Clicks on checkbox.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167776/discussion-between-andrei-gheorghiu-and-ali-gajani).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comments and chats, clicking `<label>` should not trigger any checkbox clicks.

Therefore your original CSS is basically useless because:

1. You have only 1 label for 2 checkboxes.
2. All your CSS is styling the 1 label as if there is 2 labels.

For example, this line:

```
[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked)+label,
[type="checkbox"]:checked+label {
    ...
}
```

Does nothing because there isn't enough `label` available for one of those `[type="checkbox"]`, other than the fact that they are overriding each other.

Besides, your CSS code contains a lot of self-overriding CSS similar to:

```
[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked), [type="checkbox"]:checked {...}
```

Where two opposite states use the same styling. It can be simplified to just

```
[type="checkbox"] {...}
```

**Suggested Solution**

You can transfer most styling from `label` to the `[type="checkbox"]` and `[type="checkbox"]:checked::after`.

Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xe3b2z24/5/).

Not exactly what you asked for, but I'm sure you can tweak it yourself.

Comment: @AliGajani as far as I know, there is no way for CSS to dynamically adjust the `font-size` relative to its parent's size.

Comment: Don't worry, figured it out.I just wanted to increase font-size.

Comment: @AliGajani Looks like you can do `[type="checked"]:not(:checked:)::after {...}`

Comment: Yeah I just did that a minute after I asked the question. Works

Answer (score 2):

Here's the principle:

```css
.checkGroup {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.checkGroup [type=checkbox] {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
}

cbox-image {
  position: relative;
  height: 1em;
  width: 1em;
  margin: 0 .35em;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 2px solid #eee;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.checkGroup input:checked + cbox-image:after,
.checkGroup input + cbox-image + cbox-image:after { /* checked state */
  content: '✔';
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  line-height: 0.8;
  color: #09ad7e;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.checkGroup input:checked + cbox-image + cbox-image:after,
.checkGroup input:not(:checked) + cbox-image:after { /* unchecked state */  
  content: none;
}
```

```html
<label class="checkGroup">
   <input type="checkbox" value="Turkey">
   <cbox-image></cbox-image>
   <cbox-image></cbox-image> Turkey
 </label>
```

Comment: this mechanism using CSS just blew my mind as a junior

Comment: Thanks, @Yong. Data architecture is always the most important part of code. In here there are only two states: `0` & `1` (on/off, checked/unchecked, included/excluded). If the two were different properties which could be set independently, one would need 2 controls => two inputs.